# Firefox will not cache PDF documents

Tags: firefox, pdf, browser-cache, cache-control, content-disposition

I'm serving dynamically-created GIFs and PDFs on my website using Perl. For example:

```
<img src="file.pl?f=image.gif" />
<a href="file.pl?f=doc.pdf">Document</a>
```

The content is to be cached in a visitor's browser for a predetermined amount of time, and a visitor is to be prompted to open or save a PDF prior to downloading.

To do so, I'm emitting the following HTTP response headers.

For GIFs:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: image/gif
Etag: "MD5 hash"
Expires: Wed, 05 Dec 2012 14:30:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Dec 2012 14:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1800
```

For PDFs:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="doc.pdf"
Etag: "MD5 hash"
Expires: Wed, 05 Dec 2012 14:30:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Dec 2012 14:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1800
Content-Description: file transfer
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

If I navigate to `about:cache?device=disk` in Firefox, the content is properly cached in versions **3.6.28** and older (Windows OS). However, only the GIFs are being cached in Firefox **4+**.

I've tried starting Firefox in safe mode to see if a plugin was causing the issue, but the PDFs were still not cached. I've also tried changing the content type to `application/pdf`, but no luck either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: How big are these PDFs?  Firefox 4 stopped caching files that are too large because they were usually video files completely crowding everything else out of the cache.

Comment: Most of them are under 200 KB. It might also be worthwhile to note that I'm using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in place of the `Content-Length` header for HTTP/1.1 requests.

Comment: Is Firefox handing off the PDFs to a helper application?  I believe things that get handed off to helpers are also no longer cached...

Comment: I've tested it using Ghostscript on my staging server and Acrobat on my workstation, both of which have "web browser integration" disabled. If I choose "open", the file is written to `%TEMP%`.

Comment: If I change the content type to `application/pdf`, omit the content disposition, and change Acrobat to display PDFs in the browser, Firefox caches the document; however, a visitor is no longer prompted to save or open the file. Conversely, if I send the required headers to force the save/open dialog box, even if Acrobat is set to use web browser integration, Firefox opens the PDF using the standalone version of Acrobat and `%TEMP%` is the cache folder.

Comment: Yep.  Sounds like designed behavior: in the vast majority of helper app cases caching is in fact not desirable, so it was turned off for those cases.

Comment: (I also would remove header fields that are undefined, such as "Status" and "Content-Transfer-Encoding").

Comment: xpsd300 -- so the behavior changes just because you change "attachment" to "inline"????

Comment: Julian -- thanks for heads up on non-standard headers. As for  behavior change, if I emit `octet-stream`, setting disposition to either "attachment" or "inline" produces download prompt (no browser caching). But if I emit `application/pdf`, setting disposition to "attachment" produces prompt, but setting it to "inline" opens PDF in FF (with browser caching) if Acrobat has been configured for web integration; otherwise, it acts like an attachment. Finally, when prompted to open, if I choose "Firefox" rather than Acrobat, PDF is cached to `%TEMP%` and "moz-page-thumb" entry is added to FF cache.